# Conversion from float to char[] in Java (Android)

Tags: java, android

I have an application where in onDraw() method of View I need to draw a couple of float numbers on the screen. 
In order to avoiding garbage collection I'm trying to get rid of all allocations in this method. The problem is that I want to draw floats on the screen with specified number of decimals and I can't find any information how to do it without String.format() and without using Strings at all. Even simple conversion from float to char[] seems to be a problem without Strings and allocation of memory.

So the question is how to manage this issue?

P.S. There is no way to convert them in advance before onDraw() method because numbers can be changed during user touch events (e.g. scrolling).

Comment: Does your `char[]` contains the digits or what?

Comment: Initially it doesn't contain anything. I just need to convert my number into char[] in order to use this char array in drawText() method. Unlike Strings char[] can be initialized in advance.

Comment: You realize that you cannot magically convert floats to chars and anything you could build around this would more or less be the same as using Strings?

Comment: See the docs for [`Formatter`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Formatter.html) to learn how to specify the number of decimals in your format string. (`String.format()` uses the exact same format strings.)

Comment: `String` internally is a `char[]`, so whats the problem using Strings??

Comment: and btw rendering the view and touch events are handled through the same thread (UI thread), so they should be thread safe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement your own formatter. Below is an example of a simplified formatter.

It fills the buffer from the end and returns the starting index. It will fail with `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` if float is too big for the buffer, and it won't handle negative values, infinity and NaN. I'll leave that up to you.

If you need buffer filled from beginning, just use `System.arraycopy()` to move the characters.

As you can see, the only allocation is the `char` buffer.

```
public static int format(char[] buffer, float value, int decimals) {
    float v = value;
    for (int i = 0; i < decimals; i++)
        v *= 10f;
    int num = Math.round(v);
    int idx = buffer.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < decimals; i++, num /= 10)
        buffer[--idx] = (char) ('0' + num % 10);
    if (decimals > 0)
        buffer[--idx] = '.';
    do {
        buffer[--idx] = (char) ('0' + num % 10);
    } while ((num /= 10) != 0);
    return idx;
}
```

*Test*

```
char[] buffer = new char[10];
int startIdx = format(buffer, (float)Math.PI, 4);
for (int i = startIdx; i < buffer.length; i++)
    System.out.print(buffer[i]);
System.out.println();
```

*Output*

```
3.1416
```